# MySQL query takes longer than it should on first run (but only when selecting a certain byte threshold)

Tags: php, mysql, performance

The first time I run this query on a page load, it always takes about 100ms, even though it should take about 1. I've ran the exact same query through the MySQL console and via PhpMyAdmin, and it's always fast.

I have timed it inside PHP like so:

```
$t = microtime(true);
mysql_query($sql, $this->id);
die((microtime(true)-$t)*1000);
```

If I run that exact same query a 2nd time (say by duplicating the middle line), the 2nd time runs almost instantly.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT `user_id`, `login`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `name`, `email`, ... FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`='1000' LIMIT 1
```

Through experimentation I discovered that if I reduce the number of fields I select, it suddenly runs fast. It jumps from 1ms to 100ms when I add a 26th column. It doesn't seem to matter what the 26th column is, even if it's a constant like "1", it suddenly becomes slow.

What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

---

The schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `f1` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `f2` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `f3` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `f4` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `f5` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `f6` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Anonymous',
    `f7` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `f8` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Anonymous',
    `f9` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `f10` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `f11` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
    `f12` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `f13` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `f14` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `f15` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `f16` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
    `f17` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
    `f18` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
    `f19` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
    `f20` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `f21` varchar(50) DEFAULT 'BC',
    `f22` varchar(50) DEFAULT 'Canada',
    `f23` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `f24` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `f25` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `f26` int(5) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '00000',
    `f27` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `f28` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `f29` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `f30` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `f31` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `f32` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `f33` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `f34` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `f35` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
    `f36` text NOT NULL,
    `f37` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `f38` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `f39` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `f40` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `f41` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`f1`),
    UNIQUE KEY `f2` (`f2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I've changed the field names to protect the innocent.

---

**Update:** I may have been mistaken about the magic column limit. I think it is a byte limit after all... I tried with all numbers, except for the handful of fields I actually need:

```
SELECT `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`, `f5`, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55 FROM `wx_user` WHERE `user_id`='1000' LIMIT 1
```

That runs in 1ms. If I add "56" to the end, it takes ~100ms.

---

I've done some more testing:

```
mysql_query("SELECT 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' FROM `user` WHERE `f1`='1000' LIMIT 1");
```

Somewhere between 1200 and 1300 a's it jumps from 1ms to 100ms.

I can repeat the same thing using more columns, but smaller data (ints).

This suggests to me two things:

1. it has something to do with the number of bytes being sent
2. the overhead of adding an extra column is really large, because selecting about 50 ints has the same effect of selecting a single 1300 char field.

Now that I think about it, this number is very close to the number John suggested. The 1300 chars + overhead is probably equal to that 1500 MTU limit John mentioned.

Is that a MySQL setting, or OS setting? Something I can experiment with?

Comment: 26th column? woah! that's HUGE! Y not re-strategize your database or perhaps use noSQL approach?

Comment: Why [blindly] suggest a "No SQL" approach? SQL is proven and it generally "Just Works" ..

Comment: (What happens if all the 26 columns are integers? I wonder if it could just be at the edge of some [optimized] record limit size-wize or if there being 26+ columns is of importance.. but I'm an SQL Server user ^^)

Comment: @KarmicDice: It's a legacy system; I'm not at liberty to be changing such things at the moment.

Comment: @pst: I thought it might be hitting some byte limit, so I took out some of the bigger fields and replaced them with simple ints instead... as far as I can tell, it's simply the number of columns.

Comment: @Mark Does it matter how many columns are selected, or does it only appear to be a factor of how many are in the schema?

Comment: @pst I have recently worked upon a project which was a legacy system and this update had limited time the best thing my team could suggest was noSQL for 'rigid' tables. Thus, my opinion!

Comment: @Leandro: See my comments under John's answer. Doesn't sound like cache to me.

Comment: @Leandro He got the cache part but, his question is moving from columns 1 to 26 or maybe from 25 to 26 which is killing the resources.

Comment: @Leandro That's actually *one* word ;-) Now the question comes down to if there is some 25/26 issue, as mentioned or if it is a red herring. Does it affect the cache strategy at all? Push something into a fetch? Change the query planner code execution? Etc.

Comment: @Leandro: Also, it's querying a table with 92 records using primary key. No way that takes 100ms. Average row size is 240 bytes according to PMA; so the records aren't large either.

Comment: om... sorry then. can you update the question with the create table script?

Comment: also, there are on both environment mysam? innodb? what kind?

Comment: It would be stupid to ask but, have you tried checking your mysql settings? because, I just tried the code with generated data dump and maximum benchmark that I got was 0.0012 seconds

Comment: I did select * and also select col1,col2,.........

Comment: after adding upto 56 columns, data was fetched with avg benchmark of 0.02 seconds... it went slower but, not that slow!

Comment: @KarmicDice: That's not stupid, that's what I'm thinking now too. I probably have some threshold set too low...but I don't know what setting I should be looking at. It would explain why PMA and console are faster too, if they're using different settings.

Comment: Tada! @Mark I guess by now, you have your answer :)

Comment: @KarmicDice: Just about. Seems to have something to do with this "MTU frame" and how the PHP MySQL library handles it. I don't think MySQLi suffers from this same problem, as that's what PMA uses and it isn't affected. I'm going to experiment more tomorrow and see if it magically goes away with MySQLi. I seem to pay a flat fee of ~95ms as soon as I hit that 1500 byte threshold, but beyond that it doesn't seem to matter, even if I send 15K bytes.

Comment: Sure, I am equally curious to know what could have possibly gone wrong... PS: Your 'aaaaaaaaaaaaa' experiment was hilarious to read :))

Comment: Well, I re-ran the same "aaa" test with MySQLi. Same problem :( I don't know how to get around it, unless maybe I chunk the fields and fetch them in several parts.

Comment: I split my query to fetch each of the 41-odd fields in 16-field chunks, and that does bypass the problem. The funny thing though, is if I then go and fetch the full 41 fields immediately after that, in a single query, that also runs fast, even though it should be exceeding the threshold. This makes no sense.,

Answer (score 2):

MySQl caches your query, so the second time you execute it, it loads from cache and will be much faster.

Also be sure to have the right indexes on your tables, as this can speed up things a lot.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed true, but the poster makes it sounds like there is a difference when moving 25->26 columns, which may or may not be a  red herring or another factor involved ..

Comment: @John: Yes, I'm aware of caching. But why would it run instantly *the first time* I run it after opening a fresh MySQL console then? And what's the relation with the number of columns? And why when I run the exact same query on a different database, that's fast too, as long as it's 2nd? Lastly, I've queried that very user table prior to this query (during the same pageload) with the same criteria but different fields, and that one's fast too.

Answer (score 2):

As John stated second run of the same query retrieves its result from cache so it's almost instant.

That being said there are some cases in which query might 'run' longer than it should when Xth column is being added. Few possibilities:

- the Xth column is quite big (like CHAR(65000)) and it takes time to transmit it,
- all (X-1) columns are part of index that already is in MySQL memory, but reference to Xth column forces MySQL to read row from drive,
- simultaneous query locks referenced table or causes load on CPU/hdd/memory,
- the Xth column is TEXT/BLOB and additional disk seek must be made to retrieve column value from external file (BLOBs and TEXT values are stored outside table data file),
- the Xth column adds enough bytes to row data that have to be sent from MySQL server to application that two or more network packets have to be used to transmit whole row. If You really, really, I mean ** really ** must squeeze every millisecond out of the query make sure that the query result fits in one MTU frame (usually 1500 bytes) - use sniffer to confirm it,
- other cases are quite low level and normal human being won't see them in real world.

You can also use builtin MySQL query profiling to find out which query execution stage takes so much time. Run:

```
SET profiling = 1;
[..run Your queries, each one is numbered..]
SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY n; -- SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;
SET profiling = 0;
```

You should have pretty good insight where additional time is spent. Read more about query profiling here: [MySQL Query Profiling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html)

Comment: I think I've discounted your first 4 points already; I've experimented with different column types. It seems to be some byte threshold I'm hitting. How can I "sniff" to find out what this threshold is? And why would the 2nd packet take 100x longer than the first?

Comment: I did some reading on this "MTU frame"; I thought that might be a setting I could adjust but it appears to be a hard physical limit on, what, an Ethernet cable?

Comment: I'm not an expert when it comes to low level networking but I'm pretty sure that You can change MTU. I'm not sure however if You won't have to do it both on database server and application machine. To sniff traffic I would use WireShark (AFAIR it's platform independent). Re-read, there's one more thing You can check.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's all true that MySQL has a cache and it speeds things up......

**BUT there's more than just that.** The problem is not in your query. I encounter the same thing, and the reason I can't debug it is exactly the cache: I can't produce the same problem again. It's not just MySQL, it's also the filesystem that caches things so it's completely impossible to reproduce the initial slowness - plus I don't know for sure if it could happen at all for the second time, maybe the reasons behind cause it not to happen again.  Tried to restart MySQL, tried to flush the cache, but nothing can reproduce the first run.

**And what's even more mysterious!** There's a workaround that makes no sense:  if you do a CHECK TABLE before the query (and make sure it's only the first time!), the query itself will run at normal speed.  No, not the same speed as it does when cached already; it's a normal-but-still-first-time speed.  Calling it again results instantly, as you'd expect.

Now everyone nods and says "of course, the filesystem caches the table file when doing the CHECK so next time it runs faster".  **But that's not the case.**  If I try to read the MYD file into memory with any other program (I did a simple "copy"), it doesn't solve the problem, not even if I copy the indices as well.  CHECK, however, seems to do something that really helps.

**Conclusion:** - this is not a simple "slow query" issue, this is dark sorcery.  And obviously, this workaround is not for a production environment.  I just mention it because it shows two important things:

1. The difference is NOT ONLY the cache.  There's more to it.
2. During dev time, you can apply an easy fix for the problem.

Hope this helps a few ppl out there - took me some days :)